# Return to the Land (no matter how dangerous)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story nearly 40 years ago, I thought in OMNI magazine.  It was about a famous musician who chose to return to her home planet, which was so dangerous that she might die almost immediately.  The idea was that the call of unity with one's home environment trumped the abstractions of individualism -- or something like that.  Does anyone know title, author, source?